# kableExtra:: Arabic words are not rendering properly in add_header_above

Tags: r, latex, knitr, arabic, kableextra

I want to use Arabic words in the `add_header_above` function of `kableExtra`:

```
library(kableExtra)

x1 <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "html")

Test2 <- c(" ", مواطنين = "5", `غير مواطنين` = "6")
Test3 <- c(`\textarabic{}` = " ", `\textarabic{مواطنين}` = "5",
`\textarabic{غير مواطنين}` = "6")

add_header_above(x1, Test2, escape = FALSE)

add_header_above(x1, Test3, escape = FALSE)
```

However, the Arabic words are not rendering properly. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?kableExtra::add_header_above`:

> `header` is A (named) character vector with colspan as values.

So we can build it using `setNames` as follows:

```
library(kableExtra)
x1 <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "html")
head_vec<-c("مواطنين", "غير مواطنين")
add_header_above(x1, c('',setNames(c(5,6),head_vec)))
```

Comment: Why the "?" in front of kableExtra?

Comment: @PeterMortensen to get function documentation in R you can type in R Console `?packagename::functionname`, or  `?functionname` if package has been loaded early. OR `help(functionname)`